# tikzposter \item error with \include

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzposter

I am getting `Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.` error while including a source with `item`s.

Here's a very simple way to reproduce,

main.tex

```
\documentclass[11pt,a0paper]{tikzposter}
\begin{document}
\begin{columns}

\column{0.5}
\block{A test!}{
  asddd
  \include{sensitivity}
}

\column{0.5}
\block{A test!}{
 asd
}

\end{columns}
\end{document}
```

sensitivity.tex

```
\begin{itemize}
\item sdf
\item dsf
\end{itemize}
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: using `\input{}` instead of `include{}` seem to work... but why?

Comment: `\include` is a structural command that includes at least two forced page breaks (at start and end) , it can not possibly work inside `\block` or `\column`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\include` is designed for "chapter-level" inclusions and includes a mandatory page break at the start and end of the included code, it can not work inside a box such as `\block` or even `\column` . `\input` is the command that you want here.